# Extract a tar file using tar -xzvf

Tags: bash, macos

I want to extract a tar file that I obtained by using: curl -O https://github.com/fhcrc/seqmagick/archive/0.6.1.tar.gz 
but when I try: tar -xzvf 0.6.1 
I get tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '0.6.1'

I see the file in the directory as 0.6.1.tar.gz and  I tried to do tar -xzvf 0.6.1.tar.gz but I get error Error exit delayed from previous errors.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the file `0.6.1.tar.gz`, you will see the following message

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://codeload.github.com/fhcrc/seqmagick/tar.gz/0.6.1">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

It seems that `curl` does not follow the redirect. `wget` appears to work for this purpose.

```
wget https://github.com/fhcrc/seqmagick/archive/0.6.1.tar.gz
tar xfz 0.6.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: You can pipe `curl` through `html2text -utf8` and accomplish it that way as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I'm not sure I understand the comment. Please be more specific?

Comment: When using `curl` if piped through `html2text -utf8` you would get `https://github.com/fhcrc/seqmagick/archive/0.6.1.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

I use to manipulate curl issues like bellow.
I first use `-o-` option with curl. This forces curl to "dump" contents in screen - in real time.
In your case the situation is like advised by merlin2011 :

```
$ curl -o- "https://github.com/fhcrc/seqmagick/archive/0.6.1.tar.gz"
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://codeload.github.com/fhcrc/seqmagick/tar.gz/0.6.1">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

PS: With -o- option, if the archive was correct would flood the screen with many unrecognized characters... So handle with care or pipt to tar

This movement can be solved with `-L` option of curl, which follows the moved links.
I use to include also `-s` for "silent" operation. Combine with a pipe to tar to see on screen the files content included in this archive without downloading it:

```
$ curl -sL -o- "https://github.com/fhcrc/seqmagick/archive/0.6.1.tar.gz" |tar -zt
seqmagick-0.6.1/
seqmagick-0.6.1/.gitignore
seqmagick-0.6.1/.travis.yml
seqmagick-0.6.1/CHANGELOG
seqmagick-0.6.1/CONTRIB
seqmagick-0.6.1/INSTALL
seqmagick-0.6.1/LICENSE
seqmagick-0.6.1/MANIFEST.in
<much more files here>
```

So now we have hit the correct archive. You can now use `-O` option to store the correct file in your current working directory.

```
$ curl -sLO "https://github.com/fhcrc/seqmagick/archive/0.6.1.tar.gz"
$ ls -l *.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 672141 Apr  3 11:37 0.6.1.tar.gz
$ tar -tf 0.6.1.tar.gz
seqmagick-0.6.1/
seqmagick-0.6.1/.gitignore
seqmagick-0.6.1/.travis.yml
seqmagick-0.6.1/CHANGELOG
seqmagick-0.6.1/CONTRIB
seqmagick-0.6.1/INSTALL
seqmagick-0.6.1/LICENSE
seqmagick-0.6.1/MANIFEST.in
<much more files follow>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input